# Coordinate method for solving first order linear PDE with non constant coefficient

Tags: partial-differential-equations

**Some background**
The so-called *change of coordinates method* (see Strauss) says that if $a,b$ are two constants such that $a^2 + b^2>0$ then

$
a u_x + b u_y = 0
$

is equivalent to

$
w_\xi = 0
$

provided that

$u(x,y) = w (\xi(x,y),\eta(x,y))$ 
and 
$
\begin{cases}
\xi(x,y) = a x + b y\\
\eta(x,y) = b x - a y
\end{cases} 
$

**Task** I am trying to see if there is a chance that this method works for a first order linear PDE of the form

$
a(x,y) u_x + b(x,y) u_y = 0
$

where $a$ and $b$ are functions of $(x,y)$ which satisfy $a^2 + b^2 >0$.

Some calculations show that if 
$
\begin{cases}
a \xi_x + b \xi_y = \alpha(\xi,\eta)\\
a \eta_x + b \eta_y = \beta(\xi,\eta)
\end{cases} 
$

then

$
a u_x + b u_y = 0
$

is equivalent to

$
\alpha w_\xi + \beta w_\eta = 0.
$

**Question**
Except the elementary case where $a,b$ are constants (giving $\alpha = a^2 + b^2$ and $\beta = 0$), is there any interesting example ($a,b$ are not constant) where this method can be applied? The condition on $\xi$ and $\eta$ above seems very restrictive.

Thanks for help.
m.